# Переход с Windows на Линукс

Tags: книги, linux

Привет всем!

Может сабж нережевывался сотни раз - но на данном ресурсе на нашел ответов.

Посоветуйте литературу или туторалы для полного новичка по Линуксу - особенно для перехода с винды на никсы.

Прошу не пинайте - разрешите нубу расти.

Comment: нашел неплохой ресурс по openSuse - http://suseana.ru - т.е. остановился таки на Сюсе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Идем на http://rus-linux.net/ в раздел библиотека. Читаем про основы системы.
2. Еще здесь много полезного http://linuxsam.org.ua/. Да и таких ресурсов полно.
3. Рекомендую под виндой установить виртуальную машину и уже в ней попробовать установить Linux. Чаще всего начинают с Ubuntu, но у нее сейчас слишком радикальный стандартный интерфейс. Поэтому рекомендую Kubuntu - для адаптации после винды самое то. Имеется центр управления из которого в пару кликов ставятся и сносятся программы. Хотя, немного поняв как устроен зоопарк линукс-дистрибутивов можете выбрать зверя под свои нужды.
4. Главное - не бойтесь. Тут все довольно просто. Нужно только понять основы построения файловой системы и принцип установки пакетов (программ).

Answer (score 1):

Сразу вот так многие будут советовать своё.И убунты и дебианы.

Все сидят на дебиане, у него много чего есть. Лично я на CentOs сижу меня она прет.

У всех свои заморочки и привычки.

Попробуй сначала один дистриб, потом другой, третий. Покопайся в них, какой понравится в плане оформления и установки пакетов.

А книг и блогов по этим темам просто гора!

Answer (score 0):

Для перехода с Windows на Linux помогут и блоги, которых полно в сети и их легко найти. Для этого, поверь, не нужны никакие пособия. А для изучения самой операционной систему глубоко, [Вот](http://vipbook.info/pk/os/25314-Aleksey-Stahnov.-Linux.-Vse-o-sistemah-Linuks.html)

Answer (score 0):

Можно прочитать тонну книг и не научиться. Установите Линукс на рабочую станцию и начинайте работать...Возникнут вопросы,-начнётся период обучения. Желательно полностью отказаться от Виндовс.По-моему,-самый быстрый способ.Успехов!:)

Comment: к этому и стремлюсь - установил на виртуалку сюси и минт - но многое непонятно - и фаловая структура, и как установить/убрать програмы, и вообще - КАК ВСЕ ЭТО РАБОТАЕТ!!!

Comment: Орпеделитесь с одной системой. У SuSe и Mint разные системы управления пакетами.

Answer (score 0):

По своему опыту скажу, что переход на Linux осуществлял с того что просто установил себе на комп Ubuntu. До этого только слышал что такое Linux, но не разу не видел. Как запасной вариант под рукой был RDP с доступом к Windows, где я что то делал, что не умел еще в Ubuntu. Спустя пол года я уже свободно ориентировался в Ubuntu версиях для рабочих столов. А обучение шло так, возникал вопрос, я просто открывал интернет и искал.

Answer (score 0):

Тут важны цели вашего изучения. Если вы просто хотите пользоваться дома, смотреть кино,слушать музыку и сёрфить инет, то вам достаточно в сусе открыть YaST, найти кнопку "Мененджер пакетов" и вперёд. Установит, удалит и обновит. А знать расположение и смысл каталогов не обязательно. Многое уже сделано для вас. Если же вы хотите программировать, то тут уже лучше идти на каналы мирки и официальные форумы.

Answer (score 0):

чтобы полноценно перейти на линукс нужно забыть о виндовс представить что виндовс не существует в природе нет и всё . а для десктопа для новичка рекомендую linuxMint

Answer (score 0):

А ясделал проще- установил убунту второй системой, и начал обучение на форумах http://www.ubuntologia.ru/ и   в [русскоязычном обществе убунту](http://links.readme.ru/?id=3735942180&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.ubuntu.ru%2Findex.php%234) что не понятно писал вопрос и получал ответ, в общем с пингвинами уже второй год и в винде только игрушки :)

Answer (score 0):

Уже полгода использую Ubuntu , до этого были Debian,SuSe,FreeBsd и самые разные Windows...Ubuntu очень доволен)))работает все)))

Answer (score 0):

А предлагаю ещё проще :) Запиши образ PuppyRus Linux на болванку и загрузись с неё, потому что PuppyRus Linux разрабатывался специально для тех, кто привык к Windows. Успехов =)